# Cygwin /cygdrive/c no such file or directory

Tags: cygwin, mount, nosuchfileexception

Host system: Windows Server 2008 32-bit
Installed: Cygwin

I don't know when this problem started, but one of my Rails gems uses the command `which` to determine the location of a system-installed executable. In my circumstance, it returns `/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/pngcrush` - and the file is inaccessible.

In both cygwin terminal and Windows cmd I get the following:

`ls -la /cygdrive/c` = `No such file or directory`

`mount` =

```
C:/cygwin/bin on /usr/bin type ntfs (binary,auto)
C:/cygwin/lib on /usr/lib type ntfs (binary,auto)
C:/cygwin on / type ntfs (binary,auto)
B: on /cygdrive/b type smbfs (binary,posix=0,user,noumount,auto
C: on /cygdrive/c type ntfs (binary,posix=0,user,noumount,auto)
```

Running `cd /` in Windows terminal brings me to `C:\`

`cd /cygdrive` = `The system cannot find the path specified`

FURTHER EDIT:

I can access the drives using `/c` for example, but just not `/cygdrive/c` which is what `which` returns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found [the answer](https://superuser.com/a/291820/118875) on superuser.com; moving `C:\cygwin\bin` to the front of the PATH variable fixed the issue.

Comment: Did you try restarting afterwards? The environment has to reload.

Comment: I did. Still for some strange reason, it is loading the commads coming with git.

Comment: ...and the applications you're using exist within C:\cygwin\bin? i.e., C:\cygwin\bin\which exists?

Answer (score 4):

This fix was necessary, but not sufficient, for me; one more fix was needed. I was getting the error running Bourne shell scripts which referred to other files on the localFS. All the paths checked out. It wasn't until I used Sys Internals procmon to troubleshoot that I noticed an extra char at the end of the path that wasn't resolving. Viewing the shell script in Notepad++ with View/Show Symbol/Show All Characters revealed Windows style [CR][LF] line ends, not Unix [LF]. Cygwin's sh.exe was including the [CR] on the end of the path, resulting in file not found. I appied cygwin's d2u to convert line ends, and the problem was fixed.

Comment: lifesafer mate :)